# How to update a coordinate of an existing graph object and how to check its value?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, coordinate-transformation

I have a graph `g1` as below:-

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
```

I want to update the coordinate of the 2nd vertex from {0,1} to {1,1}, so I tried below:-

```
g2 = Graph[g1, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]
```

But it doesn't work, while the coordinate of `g2`'s 2nd vertex is still {0,1}. How can I update it?

Besides, given a graph `g1` and if I want to check the vertexes' coordinates, what should I do?

Many thanks!

Comment: Property handling is awfully inconsistent. I find this particular behaviour very annoying. When you first set vertex coordinates, you can simply pass a list. When you do it the second time, you have to associate each coordinate with a vertex name, i.e. pass `Thread[VertexList[g] -> coords]` instead of `coords`.  You might want to ask Wolfram support about this, so they won't think that I'm the only person complaining about property handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g2 = SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {-1, 1}, 2 -> {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I needed to change 2 or even n of them. How can I make the change? Seems that `g2 = SetProperty[{g1, {2, 3}}, VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]` doesn't work. Is it possible to get it done without using looping like `For` or `Fold`?

Comment: Saw your edit. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.